# How to keep a file under N lines long?

Tags: bash

I have a log that should have the latest N entries. There's no problem if the file is a bit bigger a few times.

My first attempt is periodically running:

```
tail -n 20 file.log > file.log
```

Unfortunately, that just empties the file. I could:

```
tail -n 20 file.log > .file.log; mv .file.log file.log
```

However, that seems messy. Is there a better way?

Comment: It's messy, but it works, right?

Comment: There are good answers for this here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123235/problem-with-bash-output-redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123235/problem-with-bash-output-redirection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, logrotate is probably what you need.  If you still want a command line solution, this will get the job done. Ex is a line editor.  Nobody uses line editors anymore except for use in shell scripts.  Syntax is for Sh/Ksh/Bash shells.  I think it's the same in C shell.

```
ex log.001 << HERE
$
-20
1,-1d
w
q
HERE
```

Comment: Vi's father! Yep that sounds really useful.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are looking for [logrotate](http://teklimbu.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/managing-your-linuxunix-log-files-using-logrotate/).

Comment: Logrotate sounds great for general logs, but I need something more for special files not known beforehand. Also, my limit is for lines, not time. Thanks anyway, I will use it for other things.

Answer (score 1):

[logrotate](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Logrotate), with `size=xxx` where xxx is the approximate size for 20 lines, and possibly `delaycompress` to keep the previous one also human readble.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that I need more the line limit than the time period.