# Why doesnt "tail" work to truncate log files?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to manage my log file size using a cron script.  I basically want to delete all but the last 2000 lines of the log file every night.  I'm trying to run this command, but it seems to be emptying the entire file instead of doing what I want:

tail -2000 logfile.txt > logfile.txt

Does anyone know why this isn't working and/or how to accomplish what I want?  Thanks!

Comment: There are several other solutions in [linux - Problem with Bash output redirection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123235). ____________________________________________________________________________________________ Related about the common bug: [linux - How to sort a file in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29244351/) ____________________________________________________________________________________________ Same question on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: [shell - Why redirecting output sometimes produces an empty file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586443)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are overwriting the file before `tail` even starts to read it. The shell processes the `>` redirect operator, by clearing out the file first. Then it runs `tail` which has no data to read.

You can solve this by using a temporary file:

```
tail -2000 logfile.txt >logfile.tmp
mv logfile.tmp logfile.txt
```

Comment: `> logfile.txt` - means create new file

Comment: yes but if the filename is the same as the input, it would overwrite it

Comment: This only works if the process writing to the logfile closes its file descriptor.  Typical, but not always true.

Answer (score 11):

There is a problem with the accepted solution *if the process keeps the log file open*; you basically need to reuse the i-node.  Mmrobins' response is good, *logrotate* should do the right thing.

To use **tail**, you can do something (similar to Pantonza's & Greg's idea), but retain the original file by truncating the original file in-place:

```
tail -2000 logfile.txt >logfile.tmp
cat logfile.tmp > logfile.txt
rm logfile.tmp
```

To avoid a temp file, you could read into a variable, then stuff it back:

```
bash -c 'X=$(tail -2000 logfile.txt);echo "$X">logfile.txt'
```

In all cases, there's the possibility of a race condition between your truncation and the process appending to the file.  Not sure if *logrotate* handles that, none of the **tail** solutions here do.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than doing this with your own cron file you might want to look into using `logrotate` for a more robust solution.  You can rotate the logs, control how long to keep them around, email them, compress old logs, and run scripts afterwards if you want to.

See the man page [here](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)
or type `man logrotate` from the command line

Create a new logrotate file in your /etc/logrotate.d/ directory. Here's an example:

```
/var/logs/myapp/logfile.txt {
  # keep the 5 latest rotations of the log 
  rotate 5
  # rotate once the file is bigger than 2k
  size 2k
  # don't error if the file isn't there
  missingok
  # compress rotated (old) log files
  compress
  # set ownership and permissions on the new log file
  create 0640 myuser myuser
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution, without dealing with tmp files:

```
echo "`tail -2000 logfile.txt`" > logfile.txt
```

Comment: I had the problem that I was trying to truncate a file with an open file descriptor. So a tmp files wasn't an option. Thanks!

Comment: Yo! This is fantastic. You should add some context about why this works. I'm assuming it's because the backticks get processed first which sorta "stores" the last 2000 lines in the command, which then gets echoed out and replaces the `logfile.txt`. Similar to using a variable but much simpler. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Greg Hewgill is right, logfile.txt is being truncated before tail can work on it.

try:

```
tail -2000 logfile.txt > logfile2.txt; rm -f logfile.txt; mv logfile2.txt logfile.txt
```

Comment: In this case `rm` is unnecessary because `mv` will unlink the destination file during the rename.

Comment: Right... I was just being redundant :P

Comment: This only works if the process writing to the logfile closes its file descriptor. Typical, but not always true.

Comment: This is not correct, NVRAM. It works even if the process does not close its FD. It does truncate the file without error. But the logging process may not become aware of the file substitution and logging may cease to work until the [new] file is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a vim user then another option is to use `vi` instead of `tail`, to operate on the file directly:

```
vi "+execute \"normal! G2000kO\<esc>dgg\"" "+w" "+q" logfile.txt
```

The string `G2000kO\<esc>dgg` is simply the keyboard input you would use to do this with vi (the escape button must be escaped). It is very intuitive to use and covers a huge range of use cases.

vi also handles large (10+ GB) textfiles without even slowing down, so this method is very robust.