# What is mean that `grep -m 1 ` command in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I googled this command but there was not.

```
grep -m 1 "\[{" xxx.txt > xxx.txt
```

However I typed this command, error didn't occured.
Actually, there was not also result of this command.

Please anyone explain me this command's working?

Comment: The `xxx.txt > xxx.txt` part means `xxx.txt` is empty by the time `grep` reads it.

Comment: The `-m 1` option means 'stop after 1 match', but given that the file is empty, there won't be any matches anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Bash output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123235/problem-with-bash-output-redirection)

Comment: [One of many duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/597244/why-does-redirecting-the-output-of-a-file-to-itself-produce-a-blank-file)

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-m+1+%22%5C%5B%7B%22+xxx.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command reads from and writes to the same file, but not in a left-to-right fashion. In fact `> xxx.txt` runs *first*, emptying the file before the `grep` command starts reading it. Therefore there is no output. You can fix this by storing the result in a temporary file and then renaming that file to the original name.

PS: Some commands, like `sed`, have an output file *option* which works around this issue by not relying on shell redirects.